# How to solve error: Failed to create temp file 18

Tags: javascript, angularjs, blob, arraybuffer

Iam using this code to receive list base64 and print multiple pdf file, I handle this problem by convert each base64 to arraybuffer to blob pdf. But it has error *Failed to create temp file 18 : It was determined that certain files are unsafe for access within a Web application, or that too many calls are being made on file resources.*  when pass base64 many time.

```
$scope.b64toBlob = function (b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
          contentType = contentType || '';
          sliceSize = sliceSize || 1024;

          var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
          var byteArrays = [];

          for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
            var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

            var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
              byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
            }

            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

            byteArrays.push(byteArray);
          }

          var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
          return blob;
        }

return $http.post(api, params).then(function(response) {

            $scope.isSaving = false;

            var datas = response.data;

            for(var i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) {

                var uint8Array  = new Uint8Array(datas[i]);
                var arrayBuffer = uint8Array.buffer;
                var file = $scope.b64toBlob(datas[i], typeReport);
                var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
                window.open(fileURL);
            }
            $scope.clear();
        }, function(){
            $scope.isSaving = false;
        });
```

Sorry for my English. Thanks for help.

Comment: Does `javascript` make multiple requests for to same domain? Can you provide further details about context of error?

Comment: One request "$http.post(api, params).then(function(response)" to server, but it return list base64 code, each base64 (byte[]) code I want to print one file pdf, I try list base64 code have 8 element, It run, but 15 element, it  has error.

Comment: What is `.size` of `Blob` where error occurs? Is `window.open()` called eight times? With expected result of being called fifteen times?

Comment: yes, window.open called eight times. I dont know size of blob make a mistake, but size of base64 code is quite large, I received total near 300MB size of list base64,

Comment: Have you tried allowing user to call `window.open()` to print file one at a time?

Comment: you say 8 elements works, but 15 fails ... seems that this part `too many calls are being made on file resources` of the error is the relevant part then. Without knowing anything about the api you are calling, I can only guess

Comment: `But I have error` - where is this error?

Comment: @ guest271314 : I haven't yet. but how can I print file one at a time?

Comment: You can create an array of `Blob`s. At user click at element, call `URL.createObjectURL()` with `Blob` as parameter passed to `window.open()` on first element of array. Remove element from array. Continue until not elements remain in array.

Comment: thank for support. I found the error, cause by server don't return base64 code when file too big.